# android Drag and Drop for TextView causing exception

Tags: android

I am trying to use inbuilt drag and drop functionality in android 4+. I have created my custom TextView for this purpose as

```
public class DragSpotTextView extends TextView
```

The textview drag is working fine but when I drag the view on some dragspot(this is also textview) its giving exception as;

```
01-17 16:16:29.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1193): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-17 16:16:29.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1193): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to android.text.Spannable
01-17 16:16:29.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1193):     at android.widget.TextView.onDragEvent(TextView.java:11223)
01-17 16:16:29.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1193):     at android.view.View.dispatchDragEvent(View.java:13465)
01-17 16:16:29.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1193):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1104)
01-17 16:16:29.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1193):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1104)
01-17 16:16:29.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1193):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1104)
01-17 16:16:29.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1193):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1104)
01-17 16:16:29.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1193):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1104)
01-17 16:16:29.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1193):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1104)
01-17 16:16:29.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1193):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleDragEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3471)
01-17 16:16:29.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1193):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2620)
01-17 16:16:29.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1193):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-17 16:16:29.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1193):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-17 16:16:29.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1193):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
01-17 16:16:29.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1193):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-17 16:16:29.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1193):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-17 16:16:29.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1193):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-17 16:16:29.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1193):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-17 16:16:29.178: E/AndroidRuntime(1193):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can your post the code from your onDragEvent? As this is where the error is occurring

Comment: post the code of your custom class

Comment: I think you should rollback to your question and post this as answer to your question using "Answer your own question". Or entirely delete your question. Because this way, it will be in Unanswered thread even after its solved :)

Answer (score 5):

Here's another solution for those who need it. I had the same problem when I dragged the item to the `TextView` which handled drag events. Apparently, the line in the source which causes trouble is here in the `TextView.onDragEvent()` (3rd one in the following code):

```
 case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:
     final int offset = getOffsetForPosition(event.getX(), event.getY());
     Selection.setSelection((Spannable)mText, offset);
     return true;
```

The fix for me was to consume events of this type in my `OnDragListener` for this `TextView`:

```
 if (dragEvent.getAction() == DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION) return true;
```

This is a bug in Android, of course, this shouldn't normally happen.

Comment: This is also the solution to my problem and I'm very glad you pointed this out!
The owner of the thread should definitely mark your answer as solution!
Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I fixed it by creating a custom `TextView` and making sure I consumed the `DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION` event myself and let the parent class handle the other Drag events, like so:

```
public class CustomTextView extends TextView {

  @Override
  public boolean onDragEvent(DragEvent event) {
    if(event.getAction() == DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return super.onDragEvent(event);
    }
  }

}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Earlier I was using anonymous inline class for dragListener.
Now I changed it and implement OnDragListener at class level. This way I solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I read [this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=27425) and then tried replacing the following line of code:

```
ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("myLabel", "myString");
```

with:

```
ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("myLabel", ((TextView) v).getText());
```

Apparently in the onDragEvent method, the second parameter is cast to Spannable, which throws an exception when using a String.

Answer (score 0):

For me the app crashed when my drag shadow, which was **not** a TextView, entered a drop zone that **was** a TextView.

My solution in this case was to wrap the drop TextView with a FrameLayout (I'm willing to bet that any *Layout would work) - not the most elegant solution performance-wise, but not the worst either :)