# class cast exception for drag event on Android 5.0 devices

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, textview

I am working on drag and drop feature in my android activity.
User can select a grid and drag and drop to another grid cell.

It works fine on Android 4.x devices. 
But when i try to run on Android 5.0 device..i get App Crash.

Upon checking the log , I found :

> Java Class cast exception : cannot cast java.lang.String to android.text.spannable.

I cannot understand why this issue is happening.

I am using DragListener and using DragEvent to drag and drop .

The textview contains Strings. I dont know why it shows spannable cast exception

Code :

```
  ViewHolder holder  = new ViewHolder();
  holder.imageTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Day_TextView);
  holder.imageTitle.setText(mThumb9Ids[position],TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

In onClickListener

```
     mgridView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "=================on Item Long Click================== ");
            mVibrator.vibrate(VIBRATE_DURATION);                               
            ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("","");              
            DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(v);
            v.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, v, 0);
            draggedIndex = position;             
            return true;
        }

    });
```

During Drag :  ( I am getting error here while dragging The textview )

```
    class MyDragListener implements OnDragListener {
  @Override 
public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
  int action = event.getAction();
  float x = event.getX();
  float y = event.getY();
  switch (event.getAction()) {
  case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
  mfunx = x;
       mfuny = y;
       return true;
    case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:      
    Log.d(TAG, "=================[AsyncTask] Dragged Index : " + draggedIndex);
    customGridAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    int position1 = mgridView.getPositionForView((View)v);
   if(position1 == -1)
    {
        customGridAdapter.mThumb9Ids[draggedIndex] = "False";
        //customGridAdapter.mThumbIds[draggedIndex] = R.drawable.add_deviceadd_normal;
```

This ERROR is happening only on Samsung device with Android 5.0.1 version.

I dont know where i am doing the mistake

Comment: Check if one answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16340681/fatal-exception-string-cant-be-cast-to-spannable

Comment: @DanilGaponov I have added the source code . Kindly help as i tried doing the things from the link shared by you. But it didnt work out..

Answer (score 0):

This is something you should try -

handle

```
case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION: 
return true;
```

in `onDrag()` method

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19460338/609782)